# Difference between these two python implementations?

Tags: python, bigdata, pyspark

I am working on an online MOOC related to Big Data and pyspark.I came across these two implementations of a function which are then passed to a filter() transformation.

```
def ten(value):
"""Return whether value is below ten.

Args:
    value (int): A number.

Returns:
    bool: Whether `value` is less than ten.
"""
if (value < 10):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

The second implementation of this function is simply,

```
def ten(value): return value < 10
```

or equivalently when used as a lambda function in the filter() transformation

```
lambdaRDD = subRDD.filter(lambda x: x < 10)
```

Now, my question is that the first implementation returns a boolean,the second implementation returns an input number if it is less than 10.
Now,The filter transform as far as I know, returns those inputs which upon execution of the function passed to it, return TRUE.Then how does the second implementation of the function work with the filter transformation?Because this returns a number?
Please let me know if my understanding of the filter function or the function return types is wrong.

Comment: All 3 functions return booleans

Comment: if I store the result of the 2nd/3rd function in a variable, it would be a number right?

Comment: No. You can try it. `def ten(value): return value < 10` returns a boolean for `ten(some_number)`. If you assign the lambda to a variable `ten_filter = lambda x: x < 10` and call `ten_filter(some_number)`, it will return the same boolean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both implementations of the `ten` function are equivalent. The first uses a full-fledged `if` block, and the second one uses a single line, but **both do the same: return a boolean**. Same goes with the lambda function, it does the same, `true` if the number is lower than 10, `false` otherwise.

Comment: But, the second implementation  returns a number or a boolean?

Comment: A boolean, all of them return a boolean.

Comment: Got it thanks, value < 10 is a boolean expression which evaluates to True or False and that is returned.